# How to upload an array of images URLs to Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

hello how to upload an array of images urls to firestore in react native 
i tried this

```
 state = { photos: [] };

buttonPress() {

const { photos } = this.state; 

firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('images')
.add({ photos });
}
```

but the image would show like this in firestore database

```
{
"book": "Robin hood", 
"photos": "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744",
 }
```

i would like it to instead show in an array like this in firestore database

```
{
"book": "Robin hood", 
"photos":  [ "https://picsum.photos/id/1001/5616/3744"],
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by wrapping the `photos` inside `[]`. Therefore your code would be;

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('images')
  .add({ [photos] });
}
```

Also, incase you want the user to add later and not overwrite the array, I would suggest using `set` with `merge: true`.

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('images')
  .set({ [photos] }, { merge: true });
}
```